# Amino A140 development (set-top box)

Tags: javascript, html, iptv, television

Anybody was developing the software for the Amino A140 set-top box? It should be programmable with HTML/JavaScript/CSS. I have no experience with it, so any information related to development (environment, SDK, etc.), experiences are welcomed.

I know it is pretty general question...

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply for a support agreement between yourself and Amino (there is a free one available) where you must sign a NDS.  Once completed they will give you access to the firmware you will need and all the development documentation.

You need to pay a substantial amount if you want the SDK.

The basic entry level will give you access to JMACX which is a Javascript library that allows you to interact with the hardware and video player from the browser.  Your "application" would be developed in HTML/CSS/Javascript within the Opera 9 browser.

Here is a link to where you can apply
http://support.aminocom.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=1281